# "syntax error near unexpected token" when installing R-3.6.3 on Linux Mint 20.1

Tags: r, linux, installation, makefile

I have R-4.0.5 installed on my Linux Mint 20.1 platform however, I need R-3.6.3 for a class I'm taking so I'm trying to install it as described [here](https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r-source/) but I'm getting error codes after the ./configure \ command.

```
./configure \
```

> ```
> --prefix=/opt/R/${R_VERSION} \
> --enable-memory-profiling \
> --enable-R-shlib \
> --with-blas \
> --with-lapack
> ```

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
loading site script './config.site'
loading build-specific script './config.site'
./configure: line 3281: syntax error near unexpected token `WANT_R_FRAMEWORK,'
./configure: line 3281: `AM_CONDITIONAL(WANT_R_FRAMEWORK, test "x${want_R_framework}"=xyes)'
make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
sudo make 
install
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

I tried autoconf and got more errors.

```
autoconf

configure.ac:258: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_CONDITIONAL
  If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
  See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac:693: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DISABLE_STATIC
configure.ac:763: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_CHECK_LIBM
configure.ac:2002: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_LANGINFO_CODESET
configure.ac:2602: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_NLS
configure.ac:2606: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_GNU_GETTEXT_VERSION
configure.ac:2607: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_GNU_GETTEXT
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The relevant error is not "no makefile found".  The relevant error is the first one: "syntax error near unexpected token".

Comment: What was the exact URL you used to download the source files? What does `autoconf --version` say the version you are running is?